# How to use Vue slot-scope with nested components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am struggling to know where to use the `slot-scope` attribute and make sense of the documentation.

Here's a simplified version of what I need to do. You can see it running here: https://jsfiddle.net/4j4zsy0g/

**main code** - simply use the `repeater` component with content to be repeated

```
<repeater :ids="['a','b','c']">
  <h3>My Title</h3>
  <another-component/>
</repeater>
```

**repeater component**

```
<script id="repeater" type="text/x-template">
  <div class="repeater">
    <repeater-item v-for="id in ids" :key="id">
      <h2>Item {{id}}</h2>
      <slot></slot>
    </repeater-item>
  </div>
</script>
```

**repeater-item component**

```
<script id="repeater-item" type="text/x-template">
  <div class="repeater-item">
    <h1>Repeater Item</h1>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</script>
```

**sample section**

```
<script id="another-component" type="text/x-template">
  <div class="sample">
    Main content - should be in each repeater item
  </div>
</script>
```

When rendered, this is the output. You can see that the sample content is only shown once.

```
<div class="repeater">
  <div class="repeater-item">
    <h1>Repeater Item</h1>
    <h2>Item a</h2>
    <h3>My Title</h3>
    <div class="sample">Main content - should be in each repeater
    item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="repeater-item">
    <h1>Repeater Item</h1>
    <h2>Item b</h2>
    <h3>My Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="repeater-item">
    <h1>Repeater Item</h1>
    <h2>Item c</h2>
    <h3>My Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a warning message is displayed in the console:

> Duplicate presence of slot "default" found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors.

What needs to be done to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is to wrap the contents of the `repeater` in another element. That element needs to have an attribute `slot-scope`. The value of the attribute does not matter. The element can be `template` or any other element.

```
<repeater :ids="['a','b','c']">
  <template slot-scope="x">
    <h3>My Title</h3>
    <another-component/>
  </template>
</repeater>
```

This can be seen in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/4j4zsy0g/1/) by Simon Herteby.

Comment: The root of the problem (well part of it) is that the code in the question is attempting to duplicate virtual nodes (the contents of the slot). A scoped slot solves the problem because scoped slots work much like the data function in components; the slot is turned into a function that returns a *new* set of virtual nodes for each iteration. Here is a render function solution that does much the same thing. https://jsfiddle.net/4j4zsy0g/2/